# Captcha problem Magento Admin Panel

Tags: login, admin-panel, captcha

I have enabled captcha. From my admin panel I now have the problem that it keeps showing an invalid captcha message even when there is no captcha at the Admin Panel login page.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

There is a possibility to enable CAPTCHA for the Admin Panel in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > CAPTCHA` and if you have enabled it (by accident) this could be a cache issue. So try the following.

1. Flush all Magento Cache before logging in (including your browsers cache); or
2. Try another browser to login

To manually delete all chache use FTP or SSH to delete the following directories (if present)

```
[your Magento install dir]/includes/src/
[your Magento install dir]/media/css/
[your Magento install dir]/media/css_secure/
[your Magento install dir]/media/js/
[your Magento install dir]/var/cache/
```

> IMPORTANT: Don't delete the entire includes/ media/ and var/
>   directories, only the subdirectories I mentioned above!

If this doesn´t help check the `core_config_data` table in your database to see the value for `admin/captcha/enable`. If the value is 1 then Captcha for Admin is enabled. You could change it to 0 to disable it.

> IMPORTANT: Always make a backup of your database before making any changes!

Answer (score 3):

My issue is the backend 'web page isn't available'.

So it's better to do by following steps:

1) disable Captcha firstly

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like '%captcha%';

mysql> update core_config_data set value=0 where path = 'admin/captcha/enable';
```

2) use another browser to login backend 
My Chrome can't use, so i use firefox to open and signin from backend successfully.

3) use magento cache tool to flush all caches, and re-enable captcha by following sql or backend.

```
mysql> update core_config_data set value=1 where path = 'admin/captcha/enable';
```

My issues has been fixed. Hope it can help others. For all people has different environment the system, hope my experience just can be a reference.

Comment: I also needed to delete "var/cache/" and dissable the module at "app/etc/modules/"